# There is any official "Inputmask" or "a mask for a input field" in Angular 4?

Tags: angular

There is any official input mask in **angular 4**?
Would be great if we had a official lib.
I'm trying some users libs but they are broken.

Comment: What you have on your mind by saying "input mask"?

Comment: Are you referring to `<input type="password">`? https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_password

Comment: "Inputmask" or  "a mask for a input field"

Comment: https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask

Comment: this lib works! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Seems to don't have a official lib.
But I test this one that developer033 recommended  and worked very well:
github.com/text-mask/text-mask

Comment: I tried using this lib and it worked great for phone number but when I tried masking a number input it requires ```createNumberMask``` which is an addon. I could not get the addon to work with angular 4 (I forget if I got build errors or app.module import errors). Have you tried using this lib with any of their addons?